# How to add a reference to another project in my solution through Visual Studio automation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, automation, envdte, csproj

I create a new solution and add some projects to it via the [Solution2.AddFromTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/behck2xd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Now before I can build my solution successfully, I need to add a project reference from one of the projects to the other. I'm trying to navigate the VS automation object model, but cannot find how to do this.

I realize that I could just open the csproj as XML and change it on disk (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216824/automate-adding-references-in-large-vs-solution)), but then I need to handle Visual Studio detecting the project file changing and prompting to reload it.

Anyone know how to do this or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Right click on the project -> Add reference -> Solution -> choose another project to add. Isn't this sufficient?

Comment: No, I'm doing this through the Visual Studio automation API. There's no clicking UI element as Visual Studio UI isn't even displayed. See also this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer, posting for future reference.

The trick is to cast the Object property of the [EnvDTE.Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.project.aspx) to [VSProject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj.vsproject%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and then call AddProject on its References property.

```
var targetProject = (VSProject) _project.Object;
targetProject.References.AddProject(sourceProject);
```